# How to use Relation fields in parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, relational

I'm using `parse.com`, and I just want to know how to set and get relational data in a `ParseObject` Subclass, for example  [like this](https://github.com/Odd-Job/OddJob/blob/bfe222d2e7f9432c99e9daa4cb95a333fe5a4d92/AnyWall-android/Anywall/src/com/parse/anywall/AnywallPost.java).

Can you please give an example of field of type `Relation` and show me how to set and get it in the subclass?

Thanks so much in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you are really asking. `Relation` fields are sets of pointers to other `ParseObject`. You don't have to add convenience methods in the subclass if you don't need to. The super class `ParseObject` has all the methods necessary to interact with relation fields. The main entry point is `getRelation("columnName")`, which you can use on any `ParseObject` instance.

Let's say you have a `AnywallPost` class and you have set a relation column, `"likes"`, storing all `ParseUser`s that like that post. Documentation is pretty clear in explaining how to get/set.

**Set**

You don't really set anything, you just **add** a new item in the relation field.

```
ParseRelation<ParseUser> relation = anywallPost.getRelation("likes");
relation.add(parseUser1);
relation.add(parseUser2);    
anywallPost.saveInBackground();
```

A convenient method inside your subclass could be `add(ParseUser user)`:

```
public void add(ParseUser user) {
    ParseRelation<ParseUser> relation = this.getRelation("likes");
    relation.add(user);
    this.saveInBackground();
}
```

Then you can simply call `anywallPost.add(parseUser)`.

**Get**

You don't really get anything, but rather you **find** items inside the relation. This is honestly well documented in the [official docs](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#relations-using-parse-relations). A useful method inside your subclass could give you the query:

```
public ParseQuery<ParseUser> getLikes() {
    return this.getRelation("likes").getQuery();
}
```

Then you can use `ParseQuery<ParseUser> q = anywallPost.getLikes()` and use the query as you wish.